# I am using select2 multiple add....i have a list of categories in select2 dropdown with an option to add new ones

Tags: javascript, node.js, jquery-select2

Is there any feasible way to distinguish newly added options in "select2" from the selected ones, so that i don't have to perform redundant checks to add new values????

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new value, it is selected, so you should be able to add an onchange event:

```
<select class="form-control" onchange="doSomethingWith(this.value);">
```

Answer (score 0):

Very rough and ready example, jsfiddle isn't working correctly for me for some reason

https://jsfiddle.net/vd19cwxu/1/

Just set someProperty on all the existing entries

```
$('#example').select2({
  placeholder: 'Select a month'
});

$('#example').val(['JUL', 'AUG']);
$('#example').trigger('change');

$($('#example').select2('data')).each(function(i, val)
{
val.someProp = 1;
});
```

later when you come to look at the properties you can use filter to just get the new ones

```
setTimeout(function()
{
  const newEntries = $('#example').select2('data').filter(x => !x.someProp);
  alert(newEntries.length)
  alert(newEntries[0].id)
}, 5000)
```